# How to get a listbox to print a dictionaries containig item names and prices- Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, listbox

So I have a dictionary storing food items and their prices as seen here:

```
Menu = {"Mozerella":"£3.50", "Haiwann":"£3.99", "New York Style":"£4.10", "Chicken Gougons":"£3.80"}
```

However, when I run this snippet

```
choices = Menu
tkvar.set("Mozerella")
popupMenu = OptionMenu(Menu_Screen, tkvar, *choices)
```

it shows up in the list box as just the item name, no price attached to it.
How do I add the item and the price attached to it to the list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine the item and price, you can use list comprehension to merge the dictionary key and value. This will create a new list for use in the dropdown.

Try this code:

```
import tkinter as tkr
root = tkr.Tk()

# textbox for testing
selText=tkr.StringVar()
e1=tkr.Entry(root, textvariable=selText, width=42)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def OptionMenu_Select(e): # user selection changed
   selText.set(tkvar.get())  # update textbox

Menu = {"Mozerella":"$3.50", "Haiwann":"$3.99", "New York Style":"$4.10", "Chicken Gougons":"$3.80"}
choices = [m + "  " + Menu[m] for m in Menu]  # combine item and price

tkvar=tkr.StringVar()
tkvar.set(choices[0])  # set dropdown
selText.set(choices[0])  # set text box  
popupMenu = tkr.OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *choices, command = OptionMenu_Select)
popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, I had most of this code already so all I had to do was substitute my choice = with what you had given and change my tkvar.set to choice[0]. It works a treat. Thank you